# PHP Curl Extension not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

I wrote a piece which was fetching data for me correctly when I was trying it on my localhost. Its also working fine on another server. But when I transferred it to server it is showing a warning msg...

`Warning: (null)(): 4 is not a valid cURL handle resource in Unknown on line 0`.

Can anyone suggest what changes I have to make in .htacess and where I need to go in control panel to make the changes...

Here is the piece of code that I am using.

```
function multiRequest($data, $options = array()) {

  // array of curl handles
  $curly = array();
  // data to be returned
  $result = array();

  // multi handle
  $mh = curl_multi_init();

  // loop through $data and create curl handles
  // then add them to the multi-handle
  foreach ($data as $id => $d) {
$curly[$id] = curl_init();

$url = (is_array($d) && !empty($d['url'])) ? $d['url'] : $d;
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_URL,            $url);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_HEADER,         0);
curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

// post?
if (is_array($d)) {
  if (!empty($d['post'])) {
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POST,       1);
    curl_setopt($curly[$id], CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $d['post']);
  }
}

// extra options?
if (!empty($options)) {
  curl_setopt_array($curly[$id], $options);
}

curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $curly[$id]);
  }

  // execute the handles
  $running = null;
  do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
  } while($running > 0);

  // get content and remove handles
  foreach($curly as $id => $c) {
    $result[$id] = curl_multi_getcontent($c);
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $c);
  }

  // all done
  curl_multi_close($mh);

  return $result;
}

for ($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
$no = $start + $i;
$data[$i]['url']  = 'http://abc.php';
$data[$i]['post'] = array();
$data[$i]['post']['regno']   = $no;
}

$r = multiRequest($data);

// the I have a code to use the $r (result array obtained)
```

Thanks

Comment: need some code bro before we can suggest something

Comment: changing .htaccess/cpanel is not going to help this error. It's a bug in your code. probably you're overwriting your curl handle variable somewhere so that it's no longer a curl handle. Please post the relevant code. As is, this question cannot be properly answered.

Comment: This is the code that I am using

Comment: But the same code was working fine in my lappy(local server)

Comment: You will have to edit your question and post your code there.  It doesn't work too well in a comment (plus, it's in the wrong place!)

Comment: Its even working in another server. I have two. Its not working in just one of them

Comment: do a phpinfo and compare the curl part with servers on which its working and where its not working, doing a simple echo/print_r, though its a very primitive way of debugging, may also help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That doesn't mean that the cURL extension isn't working, quite the opposite. CURL is working, however when you are trying to access the options which you pass to curl, you aren't passing the curl resource handler.

For example,

```
 $ch = curl_init(); 
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
```

You need to use the $ch as your handler, which I imagine you are not doing?

As a side note, if curl wasn't installed, you would get an exception. Unless you are wrapping it in try catch/function exist.

Comment: Actually I am trying for a multi request approximately 1000 requests in a page